# Embedded signing error when envelope signing order is set

Tags: docusignapi

I am integrating a WebApp with DocuSign and use Embedded Signing to allow users sign the envelopes I am creating (and updating recipients) on the fly out of some predefined templates.

Everything works ok in the simple cases but for the templates with the signing order set (Second recipient should sign the envelope only when the first one has done) I've got *{"errorCode":"UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT","message":"The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."}* error message when creating Recipient View.

Could you advise is there a way to show the envelope for such recipient (second) if now is not her turn to sign? Or this is how Embedded Signing works and you are not able to create Recipient View for the recipient whose recipient order is not the current?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only show the embedded view for the current signer or recipient. You can have more than one current person at a time by setting their routing orders to the same number.

Eg, two signers can have routing order of 1.

Either change the template, or you may be able to update the routing order via a composite template when you send the envelope